# Kubernetes postgresql statefullset problem

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, istio

I have a 1 master and 2 nodes configured with Istio and metallb, but I cant get to works a postgresql stetefullset.
I also have configured a DNS record to redirect the request.

All pods and statefulset are Runing, but I get this error when I try to connect:

> "Expected authentication request from server, but received H"

What im doing wrong?

#### Config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: awx
  labels:
    istio-injection: enabled
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgresql-db
  namespace: awx
spec:
  serviceName: postgresql-db
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresql-db
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresql-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgresql-db
          image: postgres:12.7
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgresql-db-disk
              mountPath: /data
          # Config from Secret
          envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: postgres-db-secret
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgresdb
  # Volume Claim
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: postgresql-db-disk
        namespace: awx
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: "local-storage"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-db
  namespace: awx
  labels:
    app: postgresql-db
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgresql-db
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: postgresql-db
  namespace: awx
spec:
  host: postgresql-db
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: postgresql-db-gateway
  namespace: awx
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http-postgresql-db
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: postgresql-db-vs
  namespace: awx
spec:
  hosts:
    - "postgresql.awx.k8s"
  gateways:
  - postgresql-db-gateway
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: postgresql-db
          port:
            number: 5432
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
  namespace: awx
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
#volumeBindingMode: Immediate
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-1
  namespace: awx
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /home/xxx/storage/postgres
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - k8snode01
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-2
  namespace: awx
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /home/xxx/storage/postgres
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - k8snode02
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-db-secret
  namespace: awx
type: Opaque
stringData:
  POSTGRES_DB: awxDB
  POSTGRES_USER: awxUSER
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: awxPASSWORD
  PGDATA: /data/pgdata
```

Comment: Which version of kubernetes are you using?

Comment: Client Version: v1.21.1

Server Version: v1.21.1

Comment: Try changing `http-postgresql-db` port from 80 to 5432 and protocol from HTTP to TCP.

Comment: Didnt work, i get error: No route to host. I think is cause svc only accept 80 requests .... istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.99.56.245   192.168.x.251   10001:31009/TCP,80:30715/TCP,443:30778/TCP,15021:32501/TCP,53:32419/TCP